# How to Specify Full Url of WCF Service in Angularjs $resource

Tags: asp.net, wcf, angularjs

I have wcf service with method **GetLayoutData**. Following code i have written for this:

```
var app = angular.module('bundleModuleApp', ['ngResource', 'mydirectives']);
app.factory('masterResource', function ($resource)
{
   var src = $resource("../BundleService/BundleComponents.svc/GetLayoutData/:bundlename", { bundlename: "@bundlename" },
   {
        GetData: { method: "GET", params: {}, isArray: false },
        GetDataById: { method: "GET", params: { bundlename: "Iotasol" }, isArray: false }
   });
   return src;
});

function LayoutController($scope, masterResource) {
    $scope.LayoutBean = masterResource.GetDataById();
}
```

Now i want to specify full url of service like:

```
http://www.abc.com/BundleService/BundleComponents.svc/GetLayoutData/:bundlename
```

instead of:

```
../BundleService/BundleComponents.svc/GetLayoutData/:bundlename
```

Can any one tell me how can I pass full url of service dynamically

Comment: Have you tried absolute urls? What issue are you facing?

Comment: i have hiddenfield in for which has baseurlvalue of website

now i want to append that hiddenfield value at start of 
"BundleService/BundleComponents.svc/GetLayoutData/:bundlename"